# c# managing exceptions in a new class

Tags: c#, exception

My question is as simple as that, I want to know how can I manage exceptions from different classes and methods, in a new class defined just to handle those exceptions using C#.

Example:

- we got a class `car` with its methods
- another class `moto` with its methods
- another class `Garage` with its methods...

and I want to manage all possible exceptions thrown in any class or any method, in a new class `ExceptionsManager`.

I've tried to find out in stackoverflow similar questions, also in the MSDN, but I could only find some kind of "basic tips of managing exceptions properly".

Is this possible and if so how?

For example, some of the exceptions i must handle, and how i think i have to handle them:

- ArgumentNullException: I cant operate if the user doesnt give me the required arguments, so it should abort and warn the user.
- ArgumentException: the user gave a bad argument, so it must warn him and abort; to make him retry with a proper argument next time.
- SecurityException: if the software got not enough privileges to get a file to write over it, it cant keep operating, must abort and warn the user.
- IOException: if anybody knows any other way to handle this kind of exceptions than just aborting and warning the user, tell me.

And some other, but mostly of them are kind similar to this.

Comment: Would `ExceptionsManager` be an error logger by any chance? You may want to use an existing one such as Log4net..

Comment: There are many third party products to take care about exception tracking log4net , elmah etc.

Comment: Each book referring good coding practices is going to tell you that creating a class with `Manager` in its name is a evidence of bad design ;)

Comment: @user4221591: log4net is definitely not for "exception tracking". and basically has _nothing_ to do with the exception handling logic. It is for logging.

Comment: @Kamo i know sometimes a centralized class with many responsabilities is an evidence of bad design. But, as a example, in Mediator design Pattern, you got one object with HIGH level of responsabilities, but that gives you the chance to have so many other classes with low coupling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to put your try catches in your ExceptionManager class unless you call all the major methods from ExceptionManager methods and hanle their excceptions which is not recommended since it's not a good deisgn pattern.

```
public static class ExceptionManager
{
     static void DoCarMethod1()
     {
        try
        {
            car.method1(); 
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            //...
        }
     }
}
```

An alternative is to just pass the catched exception to your ExceptionManager class :

```
    public class Car
    {
        void method1()
        {
            try
            {
                //...
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                ExceptionManager.Handle(exception);
            }
        }
    }
    public static class ExceptionManager
    {
        public static void Handle(Exception exception)
        {
            try
            {
                //Handle Exception
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            { 
               // Log Exception inside Exception Manager
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: do you still think is a bad design pattern if i say that most of the exceptions i must handle require to abort the operation and warn the user?

Comment: @Dante'sDream Of course not my friend. With second classes I have sent, you can do what you want.

Comment: That second part is more or less what i was looking for but, one question. Why the try/catch inside the handling? I dont really understand this

Comment: @Dante'sDream because your code there shouldn't throw another exception there because it's ExceptionManager which is responsible for handling all exceptions. if an exception occur there it's unhandled. Or you can log it another way. Like my edit above.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. You were really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such magic...

Managing exceptions in a centralized way has very limited area where it is appropriate, probably the most typical use case where it makes sense logging errors and/or exit of the application.

Error handling is context sensitive by its nature. so it highly is recommended handling exceptions in their place, and do the less destructive and most creative context sensitive action like:

- revert to a default behaviour an continue the work
- retry
- retry with a less desirable option
- warn user and ask (limited usage)
- abort operation (most destructive less creative)

Note: Except abort the last resort all operations are context sensitive, and requires the control flow remain and or return back to the context. So not much could be placed to a centralized logic.

In case you still want a centralized handler there is no magic in it: (not recommended)

- Catch exception (all Exception) in all your classes by try catch construct (Note: There is no other way...)
- Pass the Exception object to a centralized class's centralized method, and do whatever what you want/could. (not so much, except of logging)

Comment: You can install an unhandled exception handler as a centralized handler. Of course, it's a method, not a class, and as you say, has limited applicability.

Comment: Well it is true, however that's not the application's exception managing strategy, only the last resort safety backup.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i didnt expect a kind of holy miracle. Most of the exceptions i must handle, will require a destructive operation, THE ABORT operation... as for example, if you want to open an existing file to write something on it, there are many exceptions such as: "not enough permissions", "file already in use", etc etc.. that can not be handled in other way than aborting  and warn the user.  And WHY i need a centralized exceptions manager? easy, i want to make my other classes easily recyclable by other users. So my point of view is: those classes will only throw exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do this ::

```
// your module classes
    try
    {
        // try block

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
            {
                excpObj.SaveException(ex);
            }   
  // separate class for error log  
    public class ExceptionLog
    {
        public static void SaveException(Exception ex)
        {
            // log your error using error logger
        }           
    }
```

Comment: If that would help also on handling them, instead of just saving and "logging", it may work...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately .Net does not support this functionality out the box, but you can create something like this using AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming), for this we can use a tool like [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) to do the aspect weaving.

The below example uses postsharp to handle exceptions and log them to the data store.

```
[Serializable]
public class HandleExceptionsAttribute : OnExceptionAspect {
    public HandleExceptionsAttribute() {
        AspectPriority = 1;
    }

    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args) {
        //Ignore the following exception 
        Type exceptionType = args.Exception.GetType();

        if (exceptionType == typeof(ValidationException)) {
            return;
        }

        //Suppress the current transaction to ensure exception is not rolled back
        using (var s = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress)) {
            //Log exception
            using (var exceptionLogContext = new ExceptionLogContext()) {
                exceptionLogContext.Set<ExceptionLogEntry>().Add(new ExceptionLogEntry(args.Exception));
                int saved = exceptionLogContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use the Aspect

```
[HandleExceptions]
public class YourClass() {

}
```

Please note the Aspect does nothing more with the exception than log it, which means the initial calling code still need to handle the `Exception` gracefully, but PostSharp does support methods where you can mark the exception as handled etc.